# using .load() to swap pages into div, but can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, load

I had [my beaches page](http://www.tremyfoel.co.uk/beaches.htm) set up with JS that swapped a beach info page into a `<div>` via hidden `<iframe>` but rejigged to use jQuery instead as a more efficient, superior solution. Experimented with a few different syntaxes:

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://yoursite.com/"+sourceURL+"");
}
```

and

```
function loadSomething{
    $("#divid").load("http://place.com/to/content.php");
}
```

and set up [a test page](http://www.tremyfoel.co.uk/jqueryTest.htm) using the latter since that seemed to work.

I've done a bit of Java programming and this is all simple stuff but I can't figure out why it isn't working. On the test page a couple of the text links work (as tested in FF and Chrome) but not the image links.
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: sorry I am using:$(function() {
    $('a[href=agreement.htm]').click(function() {
        $('#loadMe').load('agreement.htm');
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: Line 22, source, there's a syntax error.

Comment: @user1684265: Edit your actual post if you need to add more code or change it. Posting code in comments is close to unusable

Comment: Why are you appending empty strings to your jQuery selector and URL in `loadContent()`?

Comment: drrckmisn: this syntax requires the selector and url to be fed in at the link. Allows eg choice of desination div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you currently have a syntax error on the site link you've pasted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('a[href=beachPenmm.htm]').click(function() {
      $('#beachInfo').load('beachPenmm.htm');
      return false;
    });
</script>       

<script type="text/javascript">
  });
```

You aren't allowed to extend syntax between script tags. This may not be the only problem however... but fix that first :)

Comment: no worries... mistakes are easily missed when gazing at your own code for hours :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out, there are some syntax errors on your site, so you should definitely fix those first.  I just thought I'd nudge you towards some DRYer code...you've got a lot of repetition going on.  The basic upshot of what you're doing is saying "for these `<a>` tags, when you click on them, load the `<a>` tag's `href` in another element instead of the normal behavior.  Instead of setting up that jQuery on *each* image element, you could do it all in one function:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#beachInfo').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

And that will cover all of them in one fell swoop.  If you want some links to behave normally and some to load in the page, you could assign them a class like so:

```
<a class="loadInPage" href="http://...">load me in-page</a>
```

And then just modify your selector accordingly:

```
$('a.loadInPage').click(function() {
    $('#beachInfo').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

I hope this helps you clean things up a bit.  But do take care of those errors!  The Javascrcipt console is your friend!

Comment: Thak you for that I was well aware of the redundancy but was focussed on geting it to work . You're code is very much what is required thanks

Comment: Hi Ethan I've been trying your scriptlet - www.tremyfoel.co.uk/jqueryTest2.htm - but without success I can't see why logic & syntax look great to me but thats where I lack the experience....

Comment: Everything on your page looks good to me, so I suspect you might be having problems with the `load` function.  I've found it to be pretty difficult to use...it might help if you restrict it to some element in your target HTML like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hFmdm/.  The other thing you might want to consider is using an `<iframe>` instead of jQuery's `load` function.